# NameError: name 'pd' is not defined - Part 2

Tags: google-colaboratory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mi3m.png)

I have posted two different pictures for you to analyse:

1 - NameError: name 'pd' is not defined - Part 1(do you have to search in this website "stack overflow")

and

2 - NameError: name 'pd' is not defined - Part 2

Please give me some idea what could be the problem, if the system colaboratory that sometimes doesnt works properly or if I have to change the code(which I dont think be the problem).

Comment: seems like you didn't run the first block which is having package imports.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same error but later found out that I was running the import command cell as Markdown and not as a Code. I corrected this and the error clears.